# Simple C code not working properly when input.txt file is passed to it

Tags: c, fibonacci

So I have written a simple C code which generates N members of Fibonacci then writes every member into a linked list node then writes it all out.

I code in windows in Geany, but I've tested the code in ubuntu cause gcc works weird in windows. I've written the code, it compiles builds and runs, when I input everything it works good, everything is fine. 
For example the input is 1 5 2 3. 
1 is the menu choice for entering the N number of members, 
5 is the number of members the user chooses, 
2 is for generating the nodes and writing it in the nodes and 
3 is for printing it all out. 
It all works well and good there but the problem is, when I take an in.txt file with 1 5 2 3 written in it and pass it to the code with the 
cat in.txt | ./fibonacci > out.txt command in Ubuntu, my out.txt file is HUGE, with loads of the repeated outputs. If i just enter number 3 directly I get a message saying "The list is empty", which is fine. 
But when I enter only a number 3 into my in.txt file and run the command I get 150 MB of "the list is empty" in my out.txt. So when I turn in my assignement into some kind of automated assignement checker we have on my college the same thing happens and the assignment gives me a big red no-no cross. I don't really understand what the problem is, why do I have a perfectly functioning program when it's run directly but when an input file is passed to it with one single number 3 I get infinite "the list is empty" messages as my output in my out.txt file.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif

typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    int val;
} node;

int entry()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n <= 0) return -1;

    return n;

}
int make_list ( int val, node **head )
{
    node *new, *current;
    new=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(!new) return -1;

    new->val = val;
    new->next=NULL;

    if(!*head){
        *head = new;
    }else {
        for(current=*head; current->next != NULL; current= current->next);
        current->next = new;
    }

return 0;
}

int fibonacci ( int n, node **head ){
    int i, f1=0, f2=1, next=0;
    if ( n <= 0 ) return -1;
    for(i=1; i<n; i++){
    if(i==1){
        make_list(f1, head);
        continue;
    }
    if(i==2){
        make_list(f2, head);
        continue;
    }
    next = f1+f2;
    f1=f2;
    f2=next;
    make_list(next, head);
}
return 1;
}

int print( node *head){
node *current;

if(!head) return -1;

for(current=head; current!=NULL; current=current->next){
    printf("%d ", current->val);
}
return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
node *head=NULL;
char menu_choice;
int retval, n;

do {
    DEBUG("\n(1) Enter number of Fibonacci members \n(2) Generate N numbers             of Fibonacci \n(3) Print out list \n(e) Exit\n");

    scanf(" %c", &menu_choice);
    switch (menu_choice) {
        case '1':
            retval = entry();
            n = retval;
            if (retval == -1) printf("You entered negative number\n");
            break;
        case '2':
            retval = fibonacci(n+1, &head);
            if (retval==1) printf("Numbers are generated\n");
            if (retval==-1) printf("Not possible to generate numbers\n");
            break;
        case '3':
            retval = print(head);
            if (retval==-1) printf("List is empty\n");
            break;
    }
} while(menu_choice!='e');





return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why your txt is not containing the `e` command? You are not checking the `scanf` result, so it will continue looping on the input it didn't receive.

Comment: You Sir... You Sir are my saviour! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input doesn't contain the program terminating command `'e'`. In addition you are not checking the result of `scanf`. So these two in conjunction are making your program to loop infinitely with the stale value in the `menu_choice` which is `'3'` in your case, writing the corresponding output to the file.

Comment: Yep, Eugene saved me with the e part, but what do you guys mean with I am not checking my scanf result? I mean now I entered "e" at the end of input in my input file and everything seems to be working. Do I need to do anything with that scanf result you both are mentioning or? Is it fine like this, after the "e" fix?

Comment: You better check the return value of `scanf` to make sure your input didn't end abnormally (as in your case). It is returning the number of inputs populated. So if it is `0`, it did not read any character and you should terminate (I am the same Eugene, BTW :) ).

Comment: Are you talking about the scanf of the menu_choice variable or the scanf of variable N in the entry function ? In any case, I am not really sure how should I check it. Do you mean something like "if(!menu_choice)" or ?

Comment: Both should be checked, of course as your input might be terminated at any point. Return value is checked by `if (scanf(...) == 0) ...`.

Comment: Yep, okay, that patches up my entry function. if ( scanf... == 0 ) return -1. This solves all the holes in my entry function, but the problem is my menu choice entry isnt in a function.. So even when i check my  menu_choice scanf, I don't have anything to return because that's in the main function. I mean it's not anything serious but it would be nice if it was fixed

Comment: What can you possibly return? Print an error message and `break`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to initialize `n` in all scenarios

If you write 2 first `n` is left uninitialized

```
node *head=NULL;
char menu_choice;
int retval, n;        <----

do {
    DEBUG("\n(1) Enter number of Fibonacci members \n(2) Generate N numbers             of Fibonacci \n(3) Print out list \n(e) Exit\n");

    scanf(" %c", &menu_choice);
    switch (menu_choice) {
    case '1':
        retval = entry();
        n = retval;
        if (retval == -1) printf("You entered negative number\n");
        break;
    case '2':
        retval = fibonacci(n+1, &head); <-- n defined only if case 1: first
        if (retval==1) printf("Numbers are generated\n");
        if (retval==-1) printf("Not possible to generate numbers\n");
        break;
```

Comment: Yes, that one "hole" is one I know of but not sure how to fix. Tried to initialize n to 0 at first but I still get "Numbers are generated" instead of "Not possible...". Don't know why, but it's actually less of a problem than the infinite output was. Any ideas on how I should deal with this part?

Comment: @M4cX1 first of all get rid of scanf to read from keyboard. instead use fgets, then just read the first character in the buffer. e.g. `char buffer[32]; fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);` this will make sure you dont have a \n left in the stdin after you read out the character. `menu_choice = *buffer;`

Comment: @M4cX1 initialize n to 0. check in '2': whether n !=0 if yes then call fibonacci otherwise give error